# javascript replace in global situation

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to replace in this situation, all the condition get from jquery.

The source is: `1 is expansive than 2.`, i need get the result as `Apple is expansive than Pear.` but `c=c.replace(/b/gi,a);` not work. How to write it correctly?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var c=$('#source').html();
        $('span').each(function(){
            var a=$(this).html();
            var b=$(this).attr('dir');
            c=c.replace(/b/gi,a);
        });
        $('#result').html(c);
    });
</script>
<div id="source">1 is expansive than 2.</div>
<span dir="1" style="display:none;">Apple</span>
<span dir="2" style="display:none;">Pear</span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the RegExp object:

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp(b,'gi');
c = c.replace(myRegExp, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         var c=$('#source ');
         $('span').each(function(){
         var a=$(this).html();
         var b=$(this).attr('dir');
         var r= new RegExp(b, "gi") ;
         c=c.replace(r,a);
        });
        $('#result').html(c);
    });
```